# MVC 5: How do I use ajax to update PartialView returned from RenderAction(with parameter) in parent View on dropdown changed event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have tried a quite few solutions presented on StackOverflow and other sites, but I cannot get this to work.  I need to be able to update a PartialView on my page with ajax. I have managed to use unobtrusive-ajax to wire up the changed event, but I cannot get the PartialView to update.

Here is my View markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Select a Physician</label>
     @Html.DropDownList("ddlPhysicians",SelectList)ViewData["physicianList"], new { @class = "form-control" })     
     @Html.Action("GetSelectProviders", "PreCert")
</div>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
    var updatePhysPartialView = function () {
    var selectedId = $(this).val();
    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetSelectProviders")',
        dataType: "html",
        data: $form.serialize(),
    };


    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-vhn-target"));
        $target.replaceWith(data);
    });
    return false;
};

$("#ddlPhysicians").change(updatePhysPartialView);
```

Here is the controller method I would like to have called with a parameter:

```
public ActionResult GetSelectProviders(string id)
{
        PhyProviderFinalEntities phyProviderEntities = new PhyProviderFinalEntities();

        if (id == null)
        {
            var mpt = new MainProviderTable();
            return PartialView("_PhysicianData", mpt);
        }

        int myId;
        var holder = int.TryParse(id, out myId);

        if (!holder)
        {
            var mpt = new MainProviderTable();
            return PartialView("_PhysicianData", mpt);
        }

        var mptData = phyProviderEntities.MainProviderTable.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PhysId == myId);
        return PartialView("_PhysicianData", mptData);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. What I am doing wrong? Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what your trying to do. What are you expecting `var selectedId = $(this).val();` to return? (and you never use it anyway). `$form.serialize()` will post `ddlPhysicians: ##` (where `##` is is the value of the selected option) but your method expects parameter `string id` (not `string ddlPhysicians`)

Comment: "**var selectedId = $(this).val();**" was left over from an attempt to send the result to the controller that returns the partial view.  Essentially, I want to have the user select a value in ddlPhysicians and send the value to a controller that returns a typed partialview and ajax update a div with content in the partialview.  Sorry about the left over code in the question.  Desperation can make a man a little sloppy.

Comment: Then it just needs to be `$('#ddlPhysicians').change(function() { $('#xxx').load('@Url.Action("GetSelectProviders")', { id: $(this).val() }); });` where `xxx` is the `id` of the element that you want to render the partial view.

Comment: I'll be able to give this a try tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this and the javascript is called, but the Action is not.  I am not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: There is one warning. 
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
File: Create

Comment: That error is unrelated to the code you have shown. Suggest you use google to search for that error message.

Comment: I know its unrelated. I just wanted to be sure to provide all the information listed in the console.